# Ruby Yaml serialisation issue

Tags: ruby, serialization, yaml

Strange problem with serialisation, probably something I am doing wrong but not sure what it is.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Input yaml Document

```
---
ssl_user_clients:
  - first_name: donnald
    surname: duck
    email: donnald.duck@acme.corp
    country: fantasyland
    state: desert
    locality: Disney
    org_name: Acme corp
```

Expected yaml Document

```
---
ssl_user_clients:
  - first_name: donnald
    surname: duck
    password: k)NzzC+&Dg?-RY|0
    email: donnald.duck@acme.corp
    country: fantasyland
    state: desert
    locality: Disney
    org_name: Acme corp
```

Strange Result of my code:

```
---
ssl_user_clients:
- &1
  first_name: donnald
  surname: duck
  email: donnald.duck@acme.corp
  country: fantasyland
  state: desert
  locality: Disney
  org_name: Acme corp
*1:
  first_name: donnald
  surname: duck
  email: donnald.duck@acme.corp
  country: fantasyland
  state: desert
  locality: Disney
  org_name: Acme corp
  password: k)NzzC+&Dg?-RY|0
```

My Ruby Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "yaml"

def generate_activation_code(size = 16)
  charset = %w{0 1 2 3 4 6 7 9 A C D E F G H J K M N P Q R T V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k m n o p q r s t u v w x y z ! @ $ % ^ & * ( ) _ ? ~ + - = / \ | < > { } [ ]}
  (0...size).map{ charset.to_a[rand(charset.size)] }.join
end


def get_cleaned_password
    password = generate_activation_code
    password.split().collect{|x| x.strip}.join()
end


hash = YAML.load(File.read(ARGV[0]))

puts "Hash from file"
puts hash
puts
puts


for user in hash["ssl_user_clients"]
    if not user["password"]
        new_password = get_cleaned_password
    end

    pass = { "password" => new_password }
    hash[user] = user.merge pass
end


puts hash.to_yaml

open(ARGV[0], File::TRUNC) {}
File.open(ARGV[0], 'w') {|f| f.write hash.to_yaml( :Indent => 4, :UseHeader => true, :UseVersion => true ) }
```

Please may someone assist with this as this has confounded me, I really did not expect to see this.

some debug information.

```
Hash from file
{"ssl_user_clients"=>[{"first_name"=>"donnald", "surname"=>"duck", "email"=>"donnald.duck@acme.corp", "country"=>"fantasyland", "state"=>"desert", "locality"=>"Disney", "org_name"=>"Acme corp"}]}

Hash before hash.to_yaml
{"ssl_user_clients"=>[{"first_name"=>"donnald", 
                        "surname"=>"duck",
                        "email"=>"donnald.duck@acme.corp",       
                        "country"=>"fantasyland", 
                        "state"=>"desert", 
                        "locality"=>"Disney",
                        "org_name"=>"Acme corp"}], 
                      {"first_name"=>"donnald", 
                        "surname"=>"duck", 
                        "email"=>"donnald.duck@acme.corp",
                        "country"=>"fantasyland", 
                        "state"=>"desert", 
                        "locality"=>"Disney", 
                        "org_name"=>"Acme corp"}=>{"first_name"=>"donnald",
                        "surname"=>"duck", 
                        "email"=>"donnald.duck@acme.corp",
                        "country"=>"fantasyland", 
                        "state"=>"desert", 
                        "locality"=>"Disney", 
                        "org_name"=>"Acme corp", 
                        "password"=>"4?zkoff3^hmMC-<7"}}
```

The change as detailed below fixed the mangling of the yaml, however the output has indentation issues.

Great stuff, this works as expected however there is an indentation issue with output.

The following fixed the mangling as per advise given by @infused (Thanks) below:

```
for user in hash["ssl_user_clients"]
    if not user["password"]
        user["password"] = get_cleaned_password
    end
end
```

Correct output as expected.

```
---
ssl_user_clients:
  - first_name: donnald
    surname: duck
    email: donnald.duck@acme.corp
    country: fantasyland
    state: desert
    locality: Disney
    org_name: Acme corp
    password: =)%DoHHpyRrx|?v=
```

I had assumed the following would have ensured the indentation was correct.

```
to_yaml( :Indent => 4, :UseHeader => true, :UseVersion => true ) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mangling the hash in the `for user in hash["ssl_user_clients"]` loop, because `user` contains a hash and you're creating a new element using `user` as the key.

Update the passwords this way:

```
for user in hash["ssl_user_clients"]
  user['password'] = get_cleaned_password
end
```

Now `hash` will have updated passwords for each user, which you can verify with `puts hash.to_yaml`.